# How to multiply each element of a 2d array by each of its neighbours, and then sum them over the whole array

Tags: arrays, r

I am incredibly stuck on a problem for my university. I am attempting to simulate a lattice, and part of this is to find the total energy, which is done by multiplying each element of an n*n array by its four neighbours, and summing these over the whole array.

I honestly have no idea of where to start with this and am incredibly stuck. Could anyone give me a hand?

This is the code i have up to this point.

```
#defining the number of rows and columns in the lattice array
n<-20
#creating a sample of n^2 values of either -1 or 1
x<-sample(seq(-1,1,by=2), n*n, replace=T)
#plotting an n*n array with each point randomised to 1 or -1
S<-array(x, dim=c(n,n))
#printing the array
print(S)
#Plotting the Lattice, red points are 1, white is -1
image(1:20,1:20,S,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number")
#Defining the average magnetisation
Mag<-(1/(n*n))*sum(S)
#Printing the average magnetisation
print(Mag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:
I am assuming here that the borders can be multiplied by 1s in place of not having a neighbor?

```
row_lead <- rbind(S[-1, ], rep(1, n))
row_lag <- rbind(rep(1, n), S[-n, ])
col_lead <- cbind(S[ ,-1], rep(1, n))
col_lag <- cbind(rep(1, n), S[ ,-n])

# Visualize the lead/lags

p1 <- image(1:20,1:20,row_lead,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number", main = "multiply to the right")
p2 <- image(1:20,1:20,row_lag,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number", main = "multiply to the left")
p3 <- image(1:20,1:20,col_lead,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number", main = "multiply above")
p4 <- image(1:20,1:20,col_lag,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number", main = "multiply below")
# first row cant mulitply by lag and last row cant multiply by lead (same for columns). I have inserted 1s to ignore the outer boundary.
ans <- (S*row_lag*row_lead*col_lag*col_lead)

# Visualise

p5 <- image(1:20,1:20,ans,zlim=c(-1,1),ylab="Column Number",xlab="Row Number", main = "Solution")
sum(ans)
```